# Google map makes zoom in and zoom out twice in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am making an simple application using google map. In this application I have added a own custom zoom in and zoom out buttons. When I click on zoom in button then it set zoom value to 1 to map on one click but the map zoomed in twice. If I zoom in using mouse wheel then zoomed in twice.

Below is the code for zoom in that I am using...

```
var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
map.setZoom(currentZoom + 1);
```

I was trying to set zoom value in fractions such as .25 instead of 1. But map does not perform with fractions values with function `setZoom(currentZoom + .25)`.

This is very important for my application to make zoom snipped. Please provide a solution for this or any alternate that I can do the same thing.

Comment: You can star [this feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828923) in the hope Google will work on that one day...

Answer (score 1):

You **can not** do that. It must be an integer like 1, 2, 3.... Not with 0.5, 0.75 etc

Checkout the official doc for more information: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/map#Map.setZoom

Comment: The docs say setZoom gets a number param. They don't anymore specify (as they should) that the number must be an int and not a floating point.

Comment: @HelloWorld yes they have not specified it clearly but unfortunately it `setZoom()` accepts `integer` number only.

Comment: yes I am aware as I stated in my answer. Just wanted to call out the poor documentation as OP may have already read the docs but not understood a whole number is needed

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Actually increment 1 make little bit more zoom. I need small steps of zoom when I click on my custom zoom button.

DO we have any alternate for this in google map javascript   ?

Comment: @ravipandey I understood your requirement but it is not possible using JavaScript. `HelloWorld` posted some heck using CSS but I am not sure that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Though the docs don't say so anymore (they used to) setZoom method requires an integer not a floating point. You could use [CSS Zoom](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/) in conjunction with Google map zoom (setZoom(1) + CSS zoom .25 to make zoom 1.25 for example). However that trick wont work in Firefox

Comment: How can we set zoom in only google map instead of whole page?
I also have some other legend that does not need zoom.

Comment: @ravipandey - you could set zoom on the map's containing element. As VicJordan mentioned this is definitely a hack. It wont work in FF and might not work in other browsers long term